# Trying to center and bottom an image inside a div using bottom: 0 and text-align: center sends it to the bottom corner of the div

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is already centered by using `text-align: center;` in the body, im trying to place the image in the bottom of its containing div but with the following code the image is placed in the bottom but its send to the corner of the div and its no longer centered, like so:

[image no longer centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlT2C.jpg)

I have the following HTML

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas W05 Regular",arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}

.top-container{
    background-color: #f67280;
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px;
    height: 300px;
}


.mountain {

  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*transform: translate(-50%)*/

}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <h1>I´m Andres</h1>
  <p>A JAVA <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer and full stack web developer</p>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img class="mountain" src="images/mountain.png" alt="cloud-img">
</div>
```

I found the solution to this and its by using `transform: translate(-50%)` in the css properties of the .mountain, but I dont understand why the image is no longer centered and is send to the side of div when I use the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case just add   `transform: translate(-100%);` to .mountain class It will align the .mountain class item(img) in center. Because text-align:center won't work if  the position of the element is absolute.

Run the below snippet and check it.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas W05 Regular",arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}

.top-container{
    background-color: #f67280;
    position: relative;
    padding:100px;
    height: 300px;
}

.mountain {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%);

}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img"  height="100" width="100">
  <h1>I´m Andres</h1>
  <p>A JAVA <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer and full stack web developer</p>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img"  height="100" width="100">
  <img class="mountain" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img"  height="100" width="100">
</div>
</body>
```

Note:Avoid using position:absolute;.

**Absolutely positioned elements have no awareness of what's happening around them.** When a page changes size, the elements don't move in relation to each other but rather in relation to their container and the values you've set for top, left etc.

To know more:https://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/

---

Instead we can use `display:block` and `margin:auto`.

`display:block` -Displays an element as a block element `(like <p>,<h2>)`. It starts on a new line, and takes up the whole width

basically p,h2 will `display:block` property and in body u have added `text-align:center;`So p,h2 will takes up whole width and aligned center, where img will not have `display:block` property that property.
so you have to add it explicitly.

To align images in center we can simple use `margin:auto` give to img tag.And change the height to the .top-container to auto,so that height will be set automatically based on the screen size.

```
img{
display:block;
 margin:auto;
}
```

check out my code:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas W05 Regular",arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align:center;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}

.top-container{
    background-color: #f67280;
    padding: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

img{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img"  height="100" width="100">
  <h1>I´m Andres</h1>
  <p>A JAVA <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer and full stack web developer</p>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img"  height="100" width="100">
  <img class="mountain" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img"  height="100" width="100">
</div>
</body>
```

Alternate solution using `display:flex;`.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Bebas W05 Regular",arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}
.top-container{
    background-color: #f67280;
    padding: 100px;   
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img" height="100" width="100">
  <h1>I´m Andres</h1>
  <p>A JAVA <span class="pro">pro</span>grammer and full stack web developer</p>
  <img class="mountain" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img" height="100" width="100">  
  
    <img  src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/7-77046_mountain-clipart-simple-mountain-clipart-transparent-background-png.png" alt="cloud-img" height="100" width="100"/>  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I learned a lot, what I'm curious about is that when I make the image position absolute without the text-align, the image is sent to the top-left, I understand that's normal behavior because the img is taken out of the flow and placed on the corner of its paren container, then with the bottom 0 its send to the bottom. But when I put the text-align: center it's sent to the right and it evens falls out of the div parent, just like in the image link I posted, why is that? Thats the last thing I don't understand, please help my head is going nuts

Comment: If you just put bottom:0 the element will be at the bottom.So the element will not know in bottom where it to be aligned.On this situation the element inherits the alignment properties of the parent elements. @OmegaKewt  In your case u have added text align center in body tag and padding in top_container so the element is sent to right.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying by adding a wrapper and giving it `width: 100%;`. Now inside the div, you can align right to make the image appear to the end.

This is because, `position: absolute` will act by positioning the element to the specific coordinates. With a single element, if you positioned it to a certain coordinate, then other rules like `text-align:center` wont be of any effect. This is why, rather than positioning the `img`, we create a wrapper and then within the wrapper, we make `img` to align center.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mountain">
    <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="cloud-img">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mountain {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It didnt work, the wrapper appeared outside of the parent div, it worket when I added right: 0px;

Comment: yep, because i dont have the image, i cannot test it. Editing the solution

Comment: Can you explain to me please why in my code the image is no longer centered and its send to the left ?

Comment: @OmegaKewt i have included explanation in the answer